# Does Defectors do anything when triggered by Five-Year Plan

Tags: twilight-struggle

I was playing as the USSR, and Five-Year Plan was played against me.  Defectors was the randomly selected card. It has a US event, so it triggers.

But, the event in question occurs when "played by USSR during Soviet action round". Does that event occur? It seems to me that it would trigger if I were the one who played Five-Year Plan, but since it was played on a US action round, nothing happens.

The card texts are:

**Five-Year Plan**

> USSR player must randomly discard one card. If the card has a US associated
>   Event, the Event occurs immediately. If the card is a USSR associated
>   Event or an Event applicable to both players, then the card must be
>   discarded without triggering the Event.

**Defectors**

> Play in Headline Phase in order to cancel
>   USSR Headline Event, including scoring card. Canceled card
>   returns to Discard Pile.
>
> If *Defectors* is played by the USSR
>   during Soviet action round, the US gains 1 VP. (unless played on the Space Race)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If Defectors is triggered by Five-Year Plan during the Headline Phase, it cancels the USSR event if it hasn't happened yet**. From the [Twilight Struggle FAQ](http://www.gmtgames.com/nnts/FAQv5.pdf):

> Q: If Defectors is not selected by the US, but a Headline
>   event causes it to be played, is the USSR Headline event canceled?
>
> A: If the event that caused Defectors to be played would be executed before
>   the USSR event, then that event is canceled. If the USSR event has already
>   been executed, it is not canceled.

However, if Defectors is triggered as an event during the US Action phase, the event occurs, but no VP is gained (because it's not the USSR Action Round).